# Why do my line weights not show in 2D Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have set the line weights for every line on my document to 0.031", but the properties window in the forge viewer still show that my line weight is 0.00mm and the line displays with no weight.

#### Autocad with line weight enabled

[image: Autocad with line weight enabled]

#### Forge with no line weight

[image: Forge with no line weight]

Comment: I am checking with engineer team and will get back to you soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as current design the lineweights is ignored when plotting the Model tab's 2D sheet to prevent "large blobs" when you zoom into large-coordinate drawings. To see lineweights, you could view the sheets generated from the paper space layouts.
[image]